# Headset of microphone not working on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, 23.04

I bought Ryzer headphones, but the mic is not working. I can hear, only the mic is not working. I am trying literally everything, but nothing is working. Can someone help me please! Tell me if I can share any info!! Thx

I tried to add this option `snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi`, in this file `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. I tried also to configure it with pavucontrol, but nothing is working. I am trying for 6 hours.

My codecs are:

- Nvidia GPU a5 HDMI/DP
- ATI R6xx HDMI

[HDAJackRetask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ2a4.png)

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades